# Potential reasons for inflated regression coefficients?

Tags: regression, panel-data

I'm running a fixed effects regression to establish the association between exposure to online hate speech and its adoption on a large online forum. My outcome variable is the number of posts containing hate speech, and the independent variable of interest is exposure to posts containing hate speech the previous month (lagged_hateful_replies).

The results of this regression can be seen below, where I first run a model with no controls, then one only controlling for total number of forum posts and then one with many other control variables.

The controls include: the age of the forum member in months, the number of thread opening posts containing hate speech the previous month, the number of replies they received on their threads the previous month, the number of thread opening posts the previous month and the total number of posts the current month.

By looking at the adjusted R-squared, is it safe to assume the model (2) is the best since it is the simplest and compared to (3), the addition of the control variables only marginally increases the R-squared?

Also, I can't figure out why the coefficients for the lagged_hateful_replies are so different in models 2 and 3. Can anyone offer a potential explanation?

[image: Regression Results]

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to the site.

> Is it safe to assume that model 2 is better than model 3?

R^2 is not the only measure of a goodness of a model. Not only are there lots of alternate but similar measures, but there are other ideas altogether. E.g. if theory suggests that a variable is important and you find that it is not, that's a big deal. Or if the model is a key part of your hypothesis, you better include it.

Another reason seems on point here, a variable can be an important covariate. It may mediate other variables. That's happening here. Adding the variables in model 3 clearly changes the parameter for model 2. (I am using "mediate" broadly here; often people use the term only when new variables *lower* the absolute value of another parameter).

But your title is about

> Potential reasons for inflated regression coefficients

Are you sure model 3 is inflated? Maybe model 2 is deflated?

One reason for behavior like this, which is almost certainly the case here (based just on the names of the variables) is collinearity. You should investigate this. I think the best method is condition indexes (I wrote my dissertation on that). But I am pretty sure you will find it. What to do?  That depends on what your goals are.

Comment: Thanks for this answer Peter. It seems like collinearity is certainly an issue here!